# Setting up pagination on Wrapper classes in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I do have Vf page which does a search on accounts. The Vf page holds certain filters which the user selects and the query is generated based on the filters in a list of accounts.

Now the user wants an ability to remove certain records from the search result. So i have a wrapper class with a boolean field and the account record so the user can check the accounts not required on the search result and click on remove.

I wanted to have an ability to have the search results in a paged manner so that i dont have too many results displayed in the page.

How do we use standard set controllers on wrapper classes?

Answer (score 2):

Just as i posted this question.. i came across this Richards blog

http://richardvanhook.com/2009/08/03/visualforce-pagination-with-apex-lang/

The second code example was exactly what i was looking for...

Comment: updated link https://richardvanhook.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/visualforce-pagination-with-apex-lang/

Answer (score 0):

This one is helpfull to you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doCheckboxChange(cb,itemId){

        if(cb.checked==true){
            aSelectItem(itemId);
        }
        else{
            aDeselectItem(itemId);
        }

    }

</script>

<apex:form >

    <!-- handle selected item -->
    <apex:actionFunction name="aSelectItem" action="{!doSelectItem}" rerender="mpb">
        <apex:param name="contextItem" value="" assignTo="{!contextItem}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <!-- handle deselected item -->
    <apex:actionFunction name="aDeselectItem" action="{!doDeselectItem}" rerender="mpb">
        <apex:param name="contextItem" value="" assignTo="{!contextItem}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:pageBlock title="CloudClickware Pagination Sample" id="mpb">

        <!-- table of data -->
        <apex:pageBlockTable title="Contacts" value="{!contacts}" var="c">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.IsSelected}" onchange="doCheckboxChange(this,'{!c.tContact.Id}')"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!c.tContact.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.tContact.LastName}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.tContact.Title}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.tContact.Phone}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!c.tContact.Email}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <!-- count of selected items -->
        <apex:outputLabel value="[{!selectedCount} records selected]" />

        <br/>

        <!-- next, previous and page info -->
        <apex:commandLink action="{!doPrevious}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}" value="Previous" />
        <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!NOT(hasPrevious)}" value="Previous" />

        <apex:outputLabel value=" (page {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}) " />

        <apex:commandLink action="{!doNext}" rendered="{!hasNext}" value="Next" />
        <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!NOT(hasNext)}" value="Next" />

        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!del}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

---

public with sharing class wrapperpagination{

```
public PageReference del() {
    return null;
}

public String contextItem{get;set;}

private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;

private Set<Id> selectedContactIds;

public wrapperpagination()
{

    this.selectedContactIds= new Set<Id>();

    this.setCon= new ApexPages.StandardSetController( [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Phone, Email FROM Contact] );
    this.setCon.setpageNumber(1);
    this.setCon.setPageSize(10);

}

public void doSelectItem(){

    this.selectedContactIds.add(this.contextItem);

}

public void doDeselectItem(){

    this.selectedContactIds.remove(this.contextItem);

}

public Integer getSelectedCount(){

    return this.selectedContactIds.size();

}

public void doNext(){

    if(this.setCon.getHasNext())
        this.setCon.next();

}

public void doPrevious(){

    if(this.setCon.getHasPrevious())
        this.setCon.previous();

}

public List<CCWRowItem> getContacts(){

    List<CCWRowItem> rows = new List<CCWRowItem>();

    for(sObject r : this.setCon.getRecords()){
        Contact c = (Contact)r;

        CCWRowItem row = new CCWRowItem(c,false);
        if(this.selectedContactIds.contains(c.Id)){
            row.IsSelected=true;
        }
        else{
            row.IsSelected=false;
        }
        rows.add(row);
    }

    return rows;

}

/*
*   return whether previous page exists
*/
public Boolean getHasPrevious(){

    return this.setCon.getHasPrevious();

}

/*
*   return whether next page exists
*/
public Boolean getHasNext(){

    return this.setCon.getHasNext();

}

public Integer getPageNumber(){

    return this.setCon.getPageNumber();

}


Public Integer getTotalPages(){

    Decimal totalSize = this.setCon.getResultSize();
    Decimal pageSize = this.setCon.getPageSize();

    Decimal pages = totalSize/pageSize;

    return (Integer)pages.round(System.RoundingMode.CEILING);
}

public with sharing class CCWRowItem{

    public Contact tContact{get;set;}
    public Boolean IsSelected{get;set;}

    public CCWRowItem(Contact c, Boolean s){
        this.tContact=c;
        this.IsSelected=s;
    }

}
```

}

Thanks,
Raghavendra Reddy.D

Comment: could you post some useful description to your code?